# Retrieve data as array of objects || Firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im kinda new in firebase. As a first step, I would like to set a post and get calls to my newly made database in firebase.

Firebase has a lot of native functions which allows me to get elements and push them to the db. However, **I would prefer to use native get/post calls**.

My post calls seem to work just fine, it properly stores an element in the db and returns 200 status.

When I enter to my DB in firebase, I can see that it posses following data:

```
entries:
  -L1cxn3-rLgp7PsPwjV3
     author: "Mark"
     title: "Hello"
  -L1cyaOQ4TUYd3m16VfT
     autor: "Lily"
     title: "Hi"
```

So as I said before, it stores correct data. But the structure is unknown for me. It's like a map or an object.

I would like to ask you for help, how to properly retrieve it from get call.

The `get` call returns:

```
{"-L1cxn3-rLgp7PsPwjV3":{"author":"Mark","title":"Hello"},"-L1cyaOQ4TUYd3m16VfT":{"author":"Lily","title":"Hi"}};
```

I could take all keys from it `Object.keys(data)`

Then iterate over it to get it as an array - 
`Object.keys(data).map(r => data[r])`

Now I would have an array of objects.

Is it a proper way to deal with it? Should I stay with my get/post calls or I should rather use firebase built-in functions? Thank u in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Object.values()` if you want the array of objects

```js
console.log(Object.values({"-L1cxn3-rLgp7PsPwjV3":{"author":"Mark","title":"Hello"},"-L1cyaOQ4TUYd3m16VfT":{"author":"Lily","title":"Hi"}}))
```

Comment: `Object.entries()` would be a better approach.